# Pass keyval string option to babel

Tags: babel, options, package-options, kvoptions

How to pass a keyval string option given to my package to babel?

I load my package with

```
\usepackage[languages={ngerman,english}]{mylang}
```

In package mylang I want to handle this optional languages parameter and hand it over to babel. If the option is missing I want to define a default value.

My attempt:

```
\usepackage{kvoptions}
\DeclareStringOption{languages}[english,ngerman]
```

But how to go on from there?
I think the default value is set correctly but how to hand it over to babel now?
Do I need to run the default process option routine?

For a non keyval value I would use

```
\DeclareOption{languages}{\PassOptionsToPackage{\CurrentOption}{babel}}
\DeclareOption*{\OptionNotUsed}
```

Comment: `kvoptions` allow to use `DeclareOption`.

Comment: But how to use kvoptions' DeclareOption then to pass the languages keyval options to babel?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not really an answer but I want to show a minimal working example in relation to [`mhp`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/6764/mhp) answer.

`DeclareStringOption` (important is the order)

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mylang.sty}
\ProvidesPackage{mylang}
\RequirePackage{kvoptions}
 \SetupKeyvalOptions{%
   family=ML,
   prefix=ML@,
   }

\DeclareStringOption[english,ngerman]{languages}
\ProcessKeyvalOptions*
\PassOptionsToPackage{\ML@languages}{babel}
\RequirePackage{babel}



\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[languages=frenchb]{mylang}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Hint: my package name contained numbers and therefore I had to set the prefix myself since the macro `\L10n@langiages` didn't work with numbers.

Answer (score 3):

The value of an option declared with `\DeclareStringOption` is stored in the macro `\<package>@<option>`. Hence, try

```
\ProvidesPackage{mylang}

...

\usepackage{kvoptions}

\DeclareStringOption{languages}[english,ngerman]

\ProcessKeyvalOptions*

\PassOptionsToPackage{\mylang@languages}{babel}
```

If you prefer a shorter prefix than `mylang@` use `\SetupKeyvalOptions` *before* declaring options, e.g.:

```
\SetupKeyvalOptions{family=ML, prefix=ML@}
```

Comment: I get errors:
"missing \endscname inserted \ProcessOptions*"

Comment: @Sebastian: Look at the answer of Marco, he's built a minimal working example around my code. It should definitely work.

Comment: @mhp: please compare the `\DeclareStringOption` in the mwe and in your code.

Comment: @Marco: OK, I see. In contrast to Sebastian, you don't specify a default value, but an initial value for the `languages` option. In fact, this is a better approach since it allows the `babel` package to be loaded without options at all. But I don't think the error reported by Sebastian is related thereto.

Comment: @mhp: You are right.