# Extracting parts of a .sty file

Tags: packages, preamble, code

Can you load only *some* specific parts from a package while *not loading* the rest at all?
For example, from the code below I wanted to load only the `\newcommands`

```
%theorems
\usepackage{theorem}
\newtheorem{teo}{Teorema}[section]
\newtheorem{cor}[teo]{Corol\'ario}
\newtheorem{lem}[teo]{Lema}
\newtheorem{prop}[teo]{Proposi\c{c}\~ao}
%********************************************************************
%newcommands
\providecommand{\sin}{} \renewcommand{\sin}{\hspace{2pt}\textrm{sen}}
\providecommand{\tan}{} \renewcommand{\tan}{\hspace{2pt}\textrm{tg}}
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}
```

In my `.tex` file I would like to use for instance

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage['newcommands only']{file.sty}
```

or something similar to this.

Comment: The only way I can see this being done is you are able to provide a conditional to do this. This would require editing the `.sty`. Wouldn't it just be better to copy the contents you're after into a new `myfile.sty` and use `\usepackage{myfile}` instead?

Comment: Is this a package you created or some other package?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must add package options to decide via options which part should be loaded.
A list of of nearly every keyval package can you find here:
[A big list of every keyval package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26771/a-big-list-of-every-keyval-package)

An example with `kvoptions` is:

```
\ProvidesPackage{file}

...

\RequirePackage{kvoptions}

\DeclareBoolOption{newcommand}
\DeclareBoolOption{theorem}

\ProcessKeyvalOptions*
....
\iffile@newcommand
   \providecommand{\sin}{} \renewcommand{\sin}{\hspace{2pt}\textrm{sen}}
   \providecommand{\tan}{} \renewcommand{\tan}{\hspace{2pt}\textrm{tg}}
   \newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
   \newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
   \newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}
   \newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
   \newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}
\fi
\iffile@theorem
   %use theorem
   \usepackage{theorem}
   \newtheorem{teo}{Teorema}[section]
   \newtheorem{cor}[teo]{Corol\'ario}
   \newtheorem{lem}[teo]{Lema}
   \newtheorem{prop}[teo]{Proposi\c{c}\~ao}
\fi
...
\endinput
```

**EDIT:**

In relation to the comments I present a whole minimal example. To test the different input methods use the commented `usepackage`.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mypackage.sty}
\ProvidesPackage{mypackage}
\RequirePackage{kvoptions}
 \SetupKeyvalOptions{%
   family=MyPack,
   prefix=MyPack@,%prefix of all command created by kvoptions
   }

\DeclareBoolOption{newcommand}
\DeclareBoolOption{theorem}

\ProcessKeyvalOptions*
\ifMyPack@newcommand
\RequirePackage{amsfonts}
   \providecommand{\sin}{} \renewcommand{\sin}{\hspace{2pt}\textrm{sen}}
   \providecommand{\tan}{} \renewcommand{\tan}{\hspace{2pt}\textrm{tg}}
   \newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
   \newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
   \newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}
   \newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
   \newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}
\fi
\ifMyPack@theorem
   %use theorem
   \usepackage{theorem}
   \newtheorem{teo}{Teorema}[section]
   \newtheorem{cor}[teo]{Corol\'ario}
   \newtheorem{lem}[teo]{Lema}
   \newtheorem{prop}[teo]{Proposi\c{c}\~ao}
\fi
\endinput
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mypackage}
%\usepackage[newcommand]{mypackage}
%\usepackage[newcommand=true]{mypackage}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\ifdefined\Q
 defined
\else
 not defined
\fi
\end{document}
```

Comment: Marco, how to use? ``\usepackage[newcommand]{file}``?

Comment: @RegisdaSilva: `\usepackage[newcommand]{file}` or `\usepackage[newcommand=true]{file}`

Comment: Undefined control sequence \iffile@newcommand Extra \fi \fi \iffile@theorem Extra \fi \fi

Comment: @RegisdaSilva: For a complete example see: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30013/pass-keyval-string-option-to-babel

Comment: I do not quite understand those codes, would you please be more clear?

Comment: @RegisdaSilva: I edited my post.