# pass xkeyval option to class

Tags: package-writing, package-options, xkeyval

I have read about passing options to classes [in this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66591/possibility-to-pass-options-to-packages), but do not understand what I'm doing wrong. My class is defined like so, using `xkeyval` and based on `memoir`.

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{myclass}[2010/08/15 v1.0]
%%%%%
\pdfminorversion=5\pdfcompresslevel=9\pdfobjcompresslevel=2
\newif\ifcopyedit\copyeditfalse
\newif\ifdraftdoc\draftdocfalse
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\RequirePackage{xkeyval}
\DeclareOptionX{copyedit}[true]{\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{true}}{\copyedittrue}{\copyeditfalse}}
\DeclareOptionX{draft}[true]{\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{true}}{\draftdoctrue}{\draftdocfalse}}
\DeclareOptionX{10pt}{\PassOptionsToPackage{10pt}{memoir}}
\DeclareOptionX{11pt}{\PassOptionsToPackage{11pt}{memoir}}
\ExecuteOptionsX{11pt}
\ProcessOptionsX
%%%%%%
\LoadClass[openbib,fleqn]{memoir}
\RequirePackage{fixltx2e}
```

and I call it with this document:

```
\documentclass[11pt,copyedit=false,draft=false]{myclass}
\begin{document}
    some text
\end{document}
```

But in the log I see that memoir is still loading the 10pt option:

```
File: mem10.clo 2008/01/30 v0.3 memoir class 10pt size option
```

How do I make the 11pt option available to the `memoir` class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `\PassOptionsToClass` instead of `\PassOptionsToPackage`.