# Appending options to hyperref

Tags: package-writing, package-options, key-value, kvoptions

I am trying to append options to `hyperref` inside a package (say `append.sty`) I'm writing. More precisely, in the package I load the `hyperref` package and I tune it:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01]
\ProvidesPackage{append}
[2011/01/11 v0.01]

\RequirePackage{kvoptions}
\RequirePackage{kvsetkeys}
\SetupKeyvalOptions{
  family=APP,
  prefix=APP@,
  setkeys=\kvsetkeys
}
\define@key{APP}{hyperref}{%
\PassOptionsToPackage{#1}{hyperref}%
}
\ProcessKeyvalOptions*

\RequirePackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,linkcolor=blue}
\endinput
```

Note the `\hypersetup` macro. The defined option `hyperref` should pass additional setups from the user when she loads the package; for example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hyperref={pdfauthor=My Name}]{append}
\begin{document}
Hello world.... \url{www.foo.bar}
\end{document}
```

This approach is based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/78441/412). The problem is that in the resulting PDF, the author's entry in the metadata is: "MyName" (without the space). If I understand correctly, this problem occurs since `\PassOptionsToPackage` acts like `\usepackage[OPTIONS]{package}`, and in the case of the package `hyperref` this is a problem and `\hypersetup` has to be used.

**How could I solve this issue?**

Here are two attempts of mine to tackle the issue:

I tried to change `append.sty` as follow:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01]
\ProvidesPackage{append}
[2011/01/11 v0.01]

\RequirePackage{kvoptions}
\RequirePackage{kvsetkeys}
\SetupKeyvalOptions{
  family=APP,
  prefix=APP@,
  setkeys=\kvsetkeys
}
\DeclareStringOption{hyperref}
\ProcessKeyvalOptions*

\RequirePackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,linkcolor=blue,\APP@hyperref}
\endinput
```

But this yields an error:

> ! Package kvsetkeys Error: Undefined key `pdfauthor=My
>   Name'.

My second attempt is:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01]
\ProvidesPackage{append}
[2011/01/11 v0.01]

\RequirePackage{kvoptions}
\RequirePackage{kvsetkeys}
\SetupKeyvalOptions{
  family=APP,
  prefix=APP@,
  setkeys=\kvsetkeys
}
\define@key{APP}{hyperref}{%
  \def\in@hyperref{#1}
}
\ProcessKeyvalOptions*

\RequirePackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,linkcolor=blue,\in@hyperref}
\endinput
```

and I get the same error...

EDIT: A third attempt suggests that the problem is the way I try to pass options to `hyperref`.

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01]
\ProvidesPackage{append}
[2011/01/11 v0.01]

\def\in@hyperref{pdfauthor=My Name}
\RequirePackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,linkcolor=blue,\in@hyperref}
\endinput
```

Surprisingly, the following works:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01]
\ProvidesPackage{append}
[2011/01/11 v0.01]

\def\in@hyperref{My Name}
\RequirePackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,linkcolor=blue,pdfauthor=\in@hyperref}
\endinput
```

Comment: Note that `\usepackage[hyperref={pdfauthor={My Name}}]{append}` does work with your original code.

Comment: Wouldn't it be much much more easy to set the metadata after the package has been loaded? Either by using `hypersetup` or by using a wrapper command.

Comment: It is possible to load `hyperref` (or many other packages) using `\AtEndPreamble` from the `etoolbox` package. I do this all the time. Then, `hyperref` does not load until the user has had the opportunity to do things (such as set the author) in the Preamble. You can also precede loading `hyperref` with your own macro, which will set default values if the user did not set them.

Answer (score 5):

The reason the following does not work

```
\def\in@hyperref{pdfauthor=My Name}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,linkcolor=blue,\in@hyperref}
```

but the following does

```
\def\in@hyperref{My Name}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,linkcolor=blue,pdfauthor=\in@hyperref}
```

is because `\hypersetup` splits its argument first for commas and then tries to split the content between the commas on a `=`. If none is found it assumes a valueless key and therefor takes the whole content as key.

In the first code the `=` is *inside* another macro which is not yet expanded. Therefor the code in `\hypersetup` can't find it and takes `\in@hyperref` as keyname. Only then this macro is actually expanded and an not-found error is raised as there is no key with the strange name `pdfauthor=My Name`.

In order to make the code working you need to expand `\in@hyperref` first at least once. One way to do this is to use the TeX primitive `\expandafter`, which expands the token (e.g. macro) behind the next token before that one is expanded. This means `\expandafter\a\b` expands `\b` first, then `\a` is expanded. If `\b` is another `\expandafter` the whole thing repeats. So the following works:

```
\def\in@hyperref{pdfauthor=My Name}
\expandafter\hypersetup\expandafter{\in@hyperref,colorlinks,linkcolor=blue}
```

This way `\hypersetup` gets the already expanded argument `{pdfauthor=My Name,colorlinks,linkcolor=blue}`. Here `\in@hyperref` can also include multiple comma-separated key=value pairs.