# How to pass comma in value of a (xkeyval) comma separated list of values at \documentclass level?

Tags: macros, delimiters, key-value

At `\usepackage` level, `xkeyval` allows us to insert commas in value of a comma separated list of values: it is enough to enclose in braces the values containing commas. For instance, the following MCE works well.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{mypackage.sty}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1999/12/01]%
\ProvidesClass{mypackage}[2013/11/17 v0.1 A test package]%
%
\RequirePackage{xkeyval}%
%
\def\@separator{}%
%
\DeclareOptionX{separator}[]{\def\@separator{#1}}%
\ExecuteOptionsX{separator}%
\ProcessOptionsX\relax%
%
\newcommand{\twoseparatedvalues}[2]{#1\@separator#2}%
%
\end{filecontents*}
%
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[separator={,}]{mypackage}
%
\begin{document}
\twoseparatedvalues{foo}{bar}
\end{document}
```

But AFAICS, at `\documentclass` level, enclosing values in braces is not possible. For instance, the compilation of the following MCE:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{myclass.cls}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1999/12/01]%
\ProvidesClass{myclass}[2013/11/17 v0.1 A test class]%
%
\RequirePackage{xkeyval}%
%
\def\@separator{}%
%
\DeclareOptionX{separator}[]{\def\@separator{#1}}%
\ExecuteOptionsX{separator}%
\ProcessOptionsX\relax%
%
\newcommand{\twoseparatedvalues}[2]{#1\@separator#2}%
%
\LoadClass{article}%
\end{filecontents*}
%
\documentclass[separator={,}]{myclass}
%
\begin{document}
\twoseparatedvalues{foo}{bar}
\end{document}
```

throws the error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
```

BTW, passing values without commas at `\documentclass` level and passing afterwards values with commas enclosed in braces work like a charm, as in the following MCE.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{myclass.cls}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1999/12/01]%
\ProvidesClass{myclass}[2013/11/17 v0.1 A test class]%
%
\RequirePackage{xkeyval}%
%
\def\@separator{}%
%
\DeclareOptionX{separator}[]{\def\@separator{#1}}%
\ExecuteOptionsX{separator}%
\ProcessOptionsX\relax%
%
\newcommand{\twoseparatedvalues}[2]{#1\@separator#2}%
%
\LoadClass{article}%
\end{filecontents*}
%
\documentclass[separator=--]{myclass}
%
\begin{document}
\twoseparatedvalues{foo}{bar}

\setkeys{myclass.cls}{separator={,}}{}%
\twoseparatedvalues{foo}{bar}
\end{document}
```

Hence my question: how to pass comma in value of a (xkeyval) comma separated list of values at `\documentclass` level?

Comment: Load the package `kvoptions-patch` before `xkeyval`.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel make that an answer, I was going to answer `\newcommand\commasep{,}\documentclass[separator=\commasep]{myclass}` but your sounds better:-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the documentation of the keyval package `kvoptions` the separat package `kvoptions-patch` is also documented.

> LATEX’s system of package/class options has some severe limitations
>   that especially affects the value part if options are used as pair of
>   key and value.

So to fix some of the limitations you can load the package `kvoptions-patch` without loosing the facility of `xkeyval` -- But you switch to `kvoptions`, too ;-)

```
\begin{filecontents*}{myclass.cls}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1999/12/01]%
\ProvidesClass{myclass}[2013/11/17 v0.1 A test class]%
%
\RequirePackage{kvoptions-patch}%%%NEW
\RequirePackage{xkeyval}%
%
\def\@separator{}%
%
\DeclareOptionX{separator}[]{\def\@separator{#1}}%
\ExecuteOptionsX{separator}%
\ProcessOptionsX\relax%
%
\newcommand{\twoseparatedvalues}[2]{#1\@separator#2}%
%
\LoadClass{article}%
\end{filecontents*}
%
\documentclass[separator={,}]{myclass}
%
\begin{document}
\twoseparatedvalues{foo}{bar}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Indeed, `kvoptions-patch` does the trick on the MCE I submitted but unfortunately not in my real use case where the class loads `babel` and a default language: it leads to the `! Package babel Error: You haven't specified a language option.` error (I could provide a MCE that shows the trouble if asked). But I was on the right track with `kvoptions-patch` as its documentation says `xkvltxp` package has the same goal and, indeed, everything seems okay with it.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé: I didn't notice this package. Normally I am working with `kvoptions` or `l3keys`. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30013/pass-keyval-string-option-to-babel/30150#30150

Comment: I was told some key-val packages newer than `xkeyval` are more robust and I plan to switch to one of them (`kvoptions` being in the list of the ones I'll consider). But this will be after the first public release of my class which I delayed too much :)