# Pass RGB colours to custom class

Tags: color, class-options

I'm trying to pass a RGB colour code as an option to my `custom-class.cls`, so I can change the colour of a header bar and the colour of my titles in the `main-doc.tex`. The default option does work, but when I try to pass a different colour it does not work.

## Code

Currently I have the following (based on [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/250163/69578)):

```
% main-doc.tex
\documentclass[]{custom-class}

\begin{document}
\header

\section*{Title test}
Test 

\end{document}
```

And the `custom-class.cls`:

```
% custom-class.cls
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{custom-class}[2017/07/25 My custom class]
\LoadClass[a4paper]{article}

% Load required packages
\RequirePackage{titlesec} % To alter the style and spacing of titles
\RequirePackage{xcolor} % Enables the use of colours
\RequirePackage{tikz} % Draw things, needed for the header
\RequirePackage{xkeyval} % Pass options to sutom-class

% \define@key[<prefix>]{<family>}{<key>}[<default>]{<function>}
\define@key{custom-class.cls}{changecolor}[102, 204, 51]{%
    \definecolor{maincolor}{RGB}{#1}%
}

\ExecuteOptionsX{changecolor}
\ProcessOptionsX%

% Coloured header
\newcommand{\header}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    % Colored bar on top of the page
    \node [below right, fill=maincolor, minimum height=4 cm, minimum width=\paperwidth] at (current page.north west) {};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \vspace{1 em}
} 

% Change format of the section title
\titleformat{\section}{\color{maincolor}\Large}{\thesection}{0em}{}
```

## Result with a default value

[image: default option]

## Result with a custom value

When I change in `main_doc.tex` the following line:

```
\documentclass[]{custom-class}
```

into:

```
\documentclass[changecolor={206, 23, 21}]{custom-class}
```

I get the following errors:

```
line 18: Missing \begin{document}.
line 18: You can't use `macro parameter character #' in horizontal mode.
line 18: Paragraph ended before \reserved@a was complete.
line 4: \RequirePackage or \LoadClass in Options Section. \begin{document}
```

and one warning:

```
Unused global option(s): [changecolor={206, 23, 21}].
```

Comment: Put `\RequirePackage{kvoptions-patch}` before `\RequirePackage{xkeyval}`, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/145454/89417 (possible duplicate).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've tried https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/145454/140011 as Marijn suggested and adding `\RequirePackage{kvoptions-patch}` does the trick. As explained [in the package readme](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/kvoptions) (p. 11) it addresses the following:

> Latex's system of package/class options has some severe limitations that
>   especially affects the value part if options are used as pair of key and
>   value.

According to their example in your current setting `changecolor={206, 23, 21}`acutally becomes `changecolor=2062321`.

An update to the file:

```
% custom-class.cls
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{custom-class}[2017/07/25 My custom class]
\LoadClass[a4paper]{article}

% Load required packages
\RequirePackage{titlesec} % To alter the style and spacing of titles
\RequirePackage{xcolor} % Enables the use of colours
\RequirePackage{tikz} % Draw things, needed for the header
\RequirePackage{kvoptions-patch}
\RequirePackage{xkeyval} % Pass options to sutom-class

% \define@key[<prefix>]{<family>}{<key>}[<default>]{<function>}
\define@key{custom-class.cls}{changecolor}[102, 204, 51]{%
    \definecolor{maincolor}{RGB}{#1}%
}

\ExecuteOptionsX{changecolor}
\ProcessOptionsX%

% Coloured header
\newcommand{\header}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    % Colored bar on top of the page
    \node [below right, fill=maincolor, minimum height=4 cm, minimum width=\paperwidth] at (current page.north west) {};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \vspace{1 em}
} 

% Change format of the section title
\titleformat{\section}{\color{maincolor}\Large}{\thesection}{0em}{}
```

Comment: kvoptions-patch is not compatible with a current latex and will abort loading if it detects a new format. Your code will not work in this case.